# Can you enroll a VoiceProfile for Speaker recognition via the SDK after a profile is created

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to Create Voice Profiles using the Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech SDK and then later complete the enrollment process.

All examples seem do this at the same moment in time,
If you follow the examples and do

```
using (var profile = client.CreateProfileAsync(VoiceProfileType.TextIndependentVerification, "en-us"))
{
   ...
   ...
   result = await client.EnrollProfileAsync(profile, audioConfig);
   ...
   ...
}
```

However I want to  persist the ids/profiles in a database and enroll them or re-enroll
Creating a new VoiceProfile instance doesnt work and there doesnt seem to be a method for getting/fetching a profile,...
The below method doesnt work. Is there another approach for doing this or is it not possible?

```
using (var profile = new VoiceProfile(myId))
{
   ...
   ...
   result = await client.EnrollProfileAsync(profile, audioConfig);
   ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a known bug in the the SDK / Service that requires the profile type be specified when constructing a profile from an ID.

There isn't an API to provide when creating a VoiceProfile from an ID alone.

REST API for Speech Recognition verification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/speakerrecognition/verification/textdependent

Comment: Any chance there will be a GetProfile method added to the SDK?

Comment: Will be release in the near future, Please use REST API as a workaround.Here is the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/speakerrecognition/verification/textdependent

Comment: Get Profile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/speakerrecognition/verification/textdependent/getprofile